# Mxit Integration

Tags: android, integration, mxit

I need Mxit integration for my android app. Does anyone know how to integrate Mxit with the android app like Facebook. I have google it I found this link https://dev.mxit.com/docs/authentication.I tried to connect to the link as per the steps mentioned in the site but I got an error while connecting to the https://auth.mxit.com/ it shows unknown host exception.please anyone can help me to get out of this error.

Thanks in advance